# installing ROS from source, actionlib error

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS from source. First problem that I ran into is that the git repo for actionlib does not exists any more.

```
Exception caught during install: Error processing 'actionlib' : [actionlib] Checkout of git://github.com/wg-debs/actionlib-release.git version debian/ros-fuerte-actionlib_1.8.6_lucid into /home/gloin/ros-underlay/actionlib failed.
```

Does anybody know for some other repo for actionlib or how to continue with instalation process.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46848/installing-ros-from-source,-actionlib-error/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actionlib is now at https://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git. To find the release repositories, you can have a look at the distro yaml files in the rosdistro repo. For fuerte, check out [this file](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/releases/fuerte.yaml).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-10-29**:
How do we submit a ticket for this? I asked on the user mailing list, but no answers yet. Not sure where to submit a ticket to ... it isn't an actionlib issue, but an install issue.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2012-11-13**:
Bump.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-13**:
Hm. Good question. Maybe on the rosdistro github page? https://github.com/ros/rosdistro

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If someone is having the same issue. This is how I fixed it.
I downloaded the file from here: http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall and then changed the first package:

```
- git:
    local-name: actionlib
    uri: git://github.com/ros-gbp/actionlib-release.git
    version: debian/ros-fuerte-actionlib_1.8.7_precise
```

Then you should be able to run:

```
rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay file://path_to/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) with karma: 460 on 2012-10-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9